# Filter by whether column value equals a list in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to filter a Spark dataframe based on whether the values in a column equal a list. I would like to do something like this:

```
filtered_df = df.where(df.a == ['list','of' , 'stuff'])
```

Where `filtered_df` only contains rows where the value of `filtered_df.a` is `['list','of' , 'stuff']` and the type of `a` is `array (nullable = true)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can easily do:

```
df.filter(F.col(selected_col).isin([list_with_values]))
```

I find it more easy, neat and straightforward.

Answer (score 12):

**Update**:

With current versions you can use an `array` of literals:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array, lit

df.where(df.a == array(*[lit(x) for x in ['list','of' , 'stuff']]))
```

**Original answer**:

Well, a little bit hacky way to do it, which doesn't require a Python batch job, is something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, size
from functools import reduce
from operator import and_

def array_equal(c, an_array):
    same_size = size(c) == len(an_array)  # Check if the same size
    # Check if all items equal
    same_items = reduce(
        and_, 
        (c.getItem(i) == an_array[i] for i in range(len(an_array)))
    )
    return and_(same_size, same_items)
```

Quick test:

```
df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, ['list','of' , 'stuff']),
    (2, ['foo', 'bar']),
    (3, ['foobar']),
    (4, ['list','of' , 'stuff', 'and', 'foo']),
    (5, ['a', 'list','of' , 'stuff']),
]).toDF(['id', 'a'])

df.where(array_equal(col('a'), ['list','of' , 'stuff'])).show()
## +---+-----------------+
## | id|                a|
## +---+-----------------+
## |  1|[list, of, stuff]|
## +---+-----------------+
```

Comment: What does "current versions" refer to?

Answer (score 8):

You might create a udf. For example:

```
def test_in(x):
    return x == ['list','of' , 'stuff']

from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
f = udf(test_in, pyspark.sql.types.BooleanType())
filtered_df = df.where(f(df.a))
```

Comment: Is that a bit slow though?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of "[array](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array)", "[lit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lit)" and "[array_except](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_except)" function to achieve this.

1. We create an array column using `lit(array(lit("list"),lit("of"),lit("stuff"))`
2. Then we used [array_exept](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_except) function to get the values present in first array and not present in second array.
3. Then we filter for empty result array which means all the elements in first array are same as of `["list", "of", "stuff"]`

> Note: array_except function is available from spark 2.4.0.

Here is the code:

```
# Import libraries
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

# Create DataFrame
df = sc.parallelize([
    (1, ['list','of' , 'stuff']),
    (2, ['foo', 'bar']),
    (3, ['foobar']),
    (4, ['list','of' , 'stuff', 'and', 'foo']),
    (5, ['a', 'list','of' , 'stuff']),
]).toDF(['id', 'a'])

# Solution
df1 = df.filter(size(array_except(df["a"], lit(array(lit("list"),lit("of"),lit("stuff"))))) == 0)

# Display result
df1.show()
```

### Output

```
+---+-----------------+
| id|                a|
+---+-----------------+
|  1|[list, of, stuff]|
+---+-----------------+
```

I hope this helps.