# Filter PySpark dataframe based on set equality

Tags: pyspark

Suppose I have a PySpark dataframe with a column of type set:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

sc = SparkContext()    

df = sc.parallelize([
    [1, 'A'],
    [1, 'B'],
    [2, 'A'],
    [2, 'C']
]).toDF(('id', 'val'))

df_grp = df.groupBy('id').agg(f.collect_set('val').alias('val_set'))

df_grp.show()
```

The result of the `show()` is:

```
+---+-------+
| id|val_set|
+---+-------+
|  1| [B, A]|
|  2| [C, A]|
+---+-------+
```

How can I select only the row(s) where `val_set` is `[B, A]`?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207112/filter-by-whether-column-value-equals-a-list-in-spark

Comment: Thanks -- hadn't thought to search for "list" in addition to "set."